# Swift Dictionary in Objective-C as NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, swift

In my Swift class I have :

```
class Model : NSObject {

    var localSettings = Dictionary<String, NSNumber>()

    class var sharedInstance: Model {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = Model()
        }

        return Singleton.instance
    }
}
```

I call my new Swift model class from Objective-C class. I have no problems reading local settings dictionary but when I try to modify it:

```
self.model.localSettings[@"Key"] = @1;
```

I am getting compile error:

```
Expected method to write dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSDictionary<NSString *,NSNumber *> *'
```

I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you modify a dict/array in Swift, the setter gets called again, this wouldn't happen on ObjC if you added a new element to the collection, I think that's why mutable collections are bridged to their immutable equivalent.

You could create a mutable copy, modify it, and set it to the property, but that would be pretty verbose, I think a better solution would be to add methods to `Model` that modify the settings dictionary.